# Seperating this class into a header and cpp file

Tags: c++

I have difficulties with separating this class into a header and .cpp file because c++ is relatively new for me. This class is an example my teacher programmed with us in class. It isn't homework, but it will help me understand my homework.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <AstUtils.h>
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>
#include <Vector2.h>

#define WIDTH 1377
#define HEIGHT 768

using namespace std;
using namespace astu;

class Stone {
public:

Stone(double x = 0, double y = 0)
    : x(x), y(y), vx(0), vy(0)
{
//empty
}
void SetPos(double x, double y){
    this->x = x;
    this->y = y;
}

void Render() {
    SetRenderColor(255,0,0);
    RenderRectangle(x,y,20,20,true);
}

double GetPosX() const {
    return x;
}

double GetPosY() const {
    return y;
}

void SetVel(double vx, double vy){
    this->vx = vx;
    this->vy = vy;
}

void SetAcc(double ax, double ay){
    this->ax = ax;
    this->ay = ay;
}

void Update(double dt) {
    x += vx*dt;
    y += vy*dt;

    vx += ax*dt;
    vy += ay*dt;

    ax = 0;
    ay = 0;
}

private:
    double x,y;
    double vx, vy;
    double ax, ay;
};


void PlotCurve(vector<double> & vertices) {
assert(vertices.size() % 2 == 0);
assert(vertices.size() >= 4);

auto it = vertices.begin();

double x1 = *it++;
double y1 = *it++;

while(it != vertices.end()){
double x2 = *it++;
double y2 = *it++;
RenderLine(x1,y1, x2, y2);
x1 = x2;
y1 = y2;
}
}

void ReportError()
{
std::cout << "An error has occured: " << GetLastErrorMessage() << std::endl;
std::cout << GetErrorDetails() << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
if (InitApp(WIDTH,HEIGHT, "Demo") != NO_ERROR) {
ReportError();
return -1;
}

Vector2<double> center(WIDTH/2, HEIGHT/2);

Stone stone(WIDTH * 0.3, HEIGHT/2);
stone.SetVel(100, -150);

vector<double> posCurve;
posCurve.push_back(stone.GetPosX());
posCurve.push_back(stone.GetPosY());

while(!IsAppTerminated()) {
    ClearCanvas();

    Vector2 p(stone.GetPosX(), stone.GetPosY());
    Vector2 d = center - p;
    double dist = d.LengthSquared();

    d.Normalize();
    d *= 50000000 / dist;

    stone.SetAcc(d.x,d.y);

    stone.Update(GetDeltaTime());
    stone.Render();

    posCurve.push_back(stone.GetPosX());
    posCurve.push_back(stone.GetPosY());
    SetRenderColor(255,255,255);
   PlotCurve(posCurve);

    UpdateApp();
}

QuitApp();

}
```

This is what I tried:

(Didn't know how to define the constructor and also had problems with this, since the variables are in the header.)

.cpp:

```
Stone::Stone(double x = 0, double y = 0)
    : x(x), y(y), vx(0), vy(0)
{}

void SetPos(double x, double y){
    this->x = x;
    this->y = y;
}

void Render() {
    SetRenderColor(255,0,0);
    RenderRectangle(x,y,20,20,true);
}

double GetPosX() const {
    return x;
}

double GetPosY() const {
    return y;
}

void SetVel(double vx, double vy){
    this->vx = vx;
    this->vy = vy;
}

void SetAcc(double ax, double ay){
    this->ax = ax;
    this->ay = ay;
}

void Update(double dt) {
    x += vx*dt;
    y += vy*dt;

    vx += ax*dt;
    vy += ay*dt;

    ax = 0;
    ay = 0;
}
```

.h:

```
class Stone{
public:

    Stone(double x = 0, double y = 0);

    void SetPos(double x, double y);

    void Render();

    double GetPosX();

    double GetPosY();

    void SetVel(double vx, double vy);

    void SetAcc(double ax, double ay);

    void Update(double dt);

private:

    double x,y;
    double vx, vy;
    double ax, ay;
};
```

Comment: You only need to set the default values for a function's parameters once, when it's declared. In any case, I note that you wrote `Stone::Stone` but you didn't write `Stone::SetPos` or similar. Also, did you `#include` your header file anywhere in the cpp file?

Comment: More to the former point, you see how you resolved the `Stone` constructor by prefacing it with the qualifying `Stone::` ? Yeah, you need to do that for every member you likewise implemented out of the class namespace.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I will try to adjust my code. I did `#include` my header file in the .cpp and in a main.cpp

Comment: @NathanPierson So I edited my code so that every method has Stone::. The only thing I'm still confused about is the constructor. This is what I tried in the header file, so the default values are not declared: `Stone(double x, double y);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't necessarily need to move *all* implementations into the `.cpp` file. When it is sufficiently short and doesn't make use of any object external to the class, you could keep the implementation in the `.hpp` file as an inline function. This is especially true for members like `getPosX` or `getPosY`. Inlining a member like that is a gain of space but could also result in faster code.

I generally keep in the class declaration functions that I can write on a single line, like this:

```cpp
double GetPosX() const { return x; }
double GetPosY() const { return y; }
```

However, if the function requires the inclusion of another header, I move the implementation to the `.cpp` file to avoid inclusions in the header as much as possible:

```cpp
double GetPosX() const;
double GetPosY() const;
```

In `.cpp`:

```cpp
#include AnotherClass.hpp

double Stone::GetPosX() const {  return anotherClass.x; }
double Stone::GetPosY() const {  return anotherClass.y; }
```

For the constructor, you can keep it in the header, especially if it is empty, as in your example:

```cpp
Stone(double x = 0, double y = 0) : x(x), y(y), vx(0), vy(0)
{}
```

But, if it would be a more complex implementation, you should move it, too:

```cpp
// In the header
Stone(double x = 0, double y = 0);
```

```cpp
// In the cpp
Stone::Stone(double x, double y) : x(x), y(y), vx(0), vy(0) 
{
    //Complex implementation of the constructor
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the scope of the functions you define in the cpp.

Header:

```cpp
// use a "guard" to avoid duplicate includes in compilation units
#pragma once
// if compiler doesn't support "#pragma once" do
/*
#ifndef _classname_
#define _classname_
*/

class C {
  private:
    int a;
    static const int B;
  public:
    C(int); // ctor
    void setA(const int&);
    int getA() const;
};

/*
#endif
*/
```

Cpp:

```cpp
#include <header.h>

// constants need to be defined in the compilation unit,
// because the header might be included (read: copy & pasted)
// in multiple different compilation units and suddenly
// you have a class with multiple constants
static const int C::b = 4;

// constructor with member initializer list
C::C(int a) : a(a)
{
  // empty
}

// normal function
void C::setA(const int& a) {
  this->a = a;
}

// const function
int C::getA() const {
  return a;
}
```

And please do not use `using namespace` in header files, as that might mess up the code of anyone who includes them.
Remember `#include <file>` is "copy file contents here"